# `space = "free"` not eliminating dead space in ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C
                          1   23  234 324
                          2   34  534 12
                          3   56  324 124
                          4   34  234 124
                          5   123 534 654",
                  sep = "", 
                  header = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>% 
  mutate(ind = as.factor(rep(1:5, 3)))

ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  facet_grid(~variable, space = "free") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

I expect the `space = "free"` argument in `facet_grid()` to eliminate the dead space in each facet below. For example, facet 'A' should not show the space where there's an empty 'B' and empty 'C' column.

How do I eliminate this dead space in all three facets? I only want one column to show per facet and the two other blank columns in the facets should not be pseudo-plotted.

[image: spacefree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that instead you want just `scales = "free"`, as in `facet_grid(~variable, scales = "free")`, giving

[image]

I believe that is because:

> space - If "fixed", the default, all panels have the same size. If
>   "free_y" their height will be proportional to the length of the y
>   scale; if "free_x" their width will be proportional to the length of
>   the x scale; or if "free" both height and width will vary. **This
>   setting has no effect unless the appropriate scales also vary.**

So, `scales = "free"` is necessary for `space` to have an effect, but with scales` alone we already achieve what is needed in this case.